# Bootstrap and PHP file upload

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, silent

I'm trying to submit the image I'm uploading using Bootstrap jQuery plugins and PHP.

My PHP is working fine with a normal HTML form but when I'm using the Bootstrap the PHP is failing silently.

"Sorry for not uploading the code directly"

[This is my html file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qEe3DyVcm6NmZnVEt0enBHTVk/view?usp=sharing)

[This is my php file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qEe3DyVcm6QnRKRENld0xGRmc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think the problem is due to this nesting of form. Your second form is nested insde search form

Comment: Please, add the code to the question.

Comment: My code has a lot of spaces and empty lines and thus it would take a great time to tide up the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nesting of form is [not allowed](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions) in HTML.**

> Every form must be enclosed within a FORM element. There can be several forms in a single document, but the FORM element can't be nested

see [more about forms](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html) here

You have opened a form tag at `Search and Account` section.

This form is closed after the form which takes the file input.

So in effect there is nesting of forms.

So close the first form before the second form to avoid nesting